For loop spamming false in javascript
I'm trying to write a code where if a randomly generated number matches one of the numbers in for loop it should output "True" if not then false.
let min = 20;let max = 50;

let a = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);

for (let i=0; i<30; i++){
    if (i == a){
        console.log("True");
        break;
    }
    else{
        console.log("False");
    }
}

It ends up spamming false until the point it reaches the condition. Is there a way I can prevent this?

If you don't want to print the "False", then just remove the log? Or the whole else? What solution are you after if not that?

Does this answer your question? how to make this loop only write the second if once when all no matches are found also Javascript How can i make the 'else' output something only once?

Also see: searching for value in an array with a for loop in javascript

If I correctly understand, the best thing to do (well, a good thing at least) is to take the logging out of the loop entirely:
let min = 20;let max = 50;

let a = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
let message = "False";
for (let i=0; i<30; i++){
    if (i == a){
        message = "True";
        break;
    }
}
console.log(message);

And you could do that with a couple of different approaches, but the basic idea is that your code remembers what happened in the loop, and then reports that after the loop is finished.

If we're going to go into optimising the loop, then it's best to just optimise it out: if (a >= 20 && a < 30) message = "True";

@VLAZ yea lots of things could be done better here, though there are less contrived situations of course where some kind of iterative search is necessary.
